# Splunk date comparison

Tags: splunk

I need to be able to search for log entries with a specific start date, which has nothing to do with `_time`. The format is, for example, `Start_Date: 08/26/2013 4:30 PM`.

I need to add a condition in my search to specify the date, but not the time. I tried `strptime` and `strftime` unsuccessfully.

For example, I tried converting start date to a string (without time) and compare it to another string:

```
"08/26/2013"=strftime(Start_Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

This didn't work either:

```
 "08/26/2013"=strftime(strptime(Start_Date "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p"), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `*` did the trick: `Start_Date=08/26/2013*`

Answer here: http://answers.splunk.com/answers/100630/splunk-date-comparison